BlueCove cannot discover all devices
I write my codes as examples(listener,deviceDiscover)
public static void search() {
    try {
        LocalDevice ld = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        BasicInfo.logger.sendInfo("本机蓝牙名称:" + ld.getFriendlyName() + " | " );
        while (true) {
            findDevices(DiscoveryAgent.LIAC);
            //findServices();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        BasicInfo.logger.sendException(e);
    }
}

public static void findDevices(int agent) throws Exception {
    BasicInfo.logger.sendInfo("正在搜索设备喵~");
    deviceDiscovered.clear();
    LocalDevice.getLocalDevice().getDiscoveryAgent().startInquiry(agent,listener);
    synchronized (inquiryCompletedEvent) {
        inquiryCompletedEvent.wait();
        //LocalDevice.getLocalDevice().getDiscoveryAgent().cancelInquiry(listener);
        BasicInfo.logger.sendInfo("搜索设备完成喵~");
    }
}

But i can only find devices such as mobliephones.
Devices like earphones, doorlocks cannot be discovered by bluecove
is my problem?
i opensource my codes here：https://github.com/MossCG/DGLAB-OI
bluetooth part is here : https://github.com/MossCG/DGLAB-OI/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mossmc/mosscg/DGLABOI/Bluetooth/BlueToothConnect.java
replace"GIAC"to"LIAC" tried
use x64 version of bluecove

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The term Bluetooth stands for two technologies that are not compatible with each other: Bluetooth classic and Bluetooth LE.
BlueCove is an outdated programme library which, as far as I know, only supports the Bluetooth classic variant. Therefore, you will only be able to find Bluetooth classic devices with its help.
Newer devices, such as the Doorlock in your case, generally use the newer Bluetooth LE technology. You cannot find these devices with the BlueCove Library.
